# How to clear text format in notepad++?

Tags: styles, notepad++

I am wondering how to clear text format/styles in notepad++, as I did not find a function to do that.

So for example, for a text file, if I copied and pasted a link in the text file, from a xml file, how do I clear the link but only reserve the text.

```
Url="[http://www.allbookstores.com/search?type=any&amp;q=psychology&amp;order_by=&amp;page=&amp;limit=&amp;Go.x=7&amp;Go.y=8][1]"
```

the url is a xml attribute that contains a link.

cheers

Comment: please extend your question by showing example of text with formatting tags

Answer (score 0):

in order to change your example to

```
http://www.allbookstores.com/search?type=any&amp;q=psychology&amp;order_by=&amp;page=&amp;limit=&amp;Go.x=7&amp;Go.y=8
```

you have to

1. perform **regex** replace, search `Url="\[(.*)\]\[\d*\]"`, replace by `\1`
2. perform **normal** replace, search `&amp;`, replace by `&`

If you wish to convert the value differently, please provide more precise source/target example.